# Configure ASP.NET validators to only block specific POST action

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I'm using ASP.NET validators to validate a series of textboxes. By default, any POST action on the page is blocked until all textboxes are valid.

It so happens that, aside from the POST action associated to the submit button, I have other POST actions that do not require the textboxes to be valid.

Is there a way to configure ASP.NET to only block the POST action froma specific button, or to disable this altogether? Preferably done in codebehind

Comment: Can you not just set CausesValidation to false on the postback buttons that shouldn't trigger validation?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Thanks! This works perfectly! If you want to put your comment into an answer I'd be happy to mark it as accepted!

Comment: Happy to help and put it into an answer for you @Cristiano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CausesValidation property to ensure whether or not a webcontrol should trigger validation.